# React Native build errors

Tags: objective-c, react-native

When trying to build a native module from Xcode and importing RCTUIManager   (#import "React/RCTUIManager.h") I am getting a lot of errors related to RCTBridgeModule. The errors are:

- "Redefinition of RCTMethodInfo"
- "Cannot find protocol declaration for "RCTBridgeModule" and other errors

If I don't import RCTUIManager everything works fine, but I need this for using:

```
[self.bridge.uiManager addUIBlock:^(RCTUIManager *uiManager, NSDictionary<NSNumber *, UIView *> *viewRegistry) {
    UIView *view = viewRegistry[[NSNumber numberWithInt:tagId]];
    if (![view isKindOfClass:[UIView class]]) {
        RCTLog(@"expecting UIView, got: %@", view);
    }
    else {

    }
}];
```

How can I get rid of this errors? I am using the latest version of React Native (0.57.8) and Xcode (10.2).

Comment: 0.59.5 is the latest version of React Native (0.59.4 at the time you posted this)

Answer (score 0):

Try with `#import <React/RCTUIManager.h>`?

Also it would be a good idea to clean the project before building. You can do that selecting `Product -> Clean Build Folder` or by pressing `CMD` `SHIFT` and `K`.

Comment: I've tried with #import <React/RCTUIManager.h> . Same errors. And I cleaned the project also.

Comment: Can you add the stack trace?

Comment: The problem was with importing of "RCTBridgeModule" in the .h file. It seems that it matters how you import "RCTBridgeModule" and then importing of RCTUIManager. So, is fixed.